# Continuity of a linear operator defined on polynomials

Tags: polynomials, continuity, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I am struggling with this seemingly easy problem.

Let $E = \mathbb{R}[X]$ equipped with the following norm: $||P||_\infty := \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} | P(x) |$ and define $\delta_a : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the linear transformation defined by:  $\forall P \in E, \delta_a(P) = P(a)$. This transformation gives nothing but the value of $P$ at point $a$. For which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\delta_a$ continuous? For such $a$, compute the norm of $\delta_a$.

From the definition given in my lessons, the transformation is continuous if there exists a $c > 0$ such that
$$ \forall P \in E, ||\delta_a(P)||_{\mathbb{R}} \leq c ||P||_\infty \iff |P(a)| \leq c \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |P(x)| $$

I have no idea how to find such a constant. The case $a \in [0, 1]$ obviously works, but since the norm we're provided with is only defined on this interval, what can we say about other values of $a$ ?

When $a \in [0, 1]$, I don't know how to work out a more explicit expression for the norm of the operator, other than the definition of the operator norm:

$$|||\delta_a||| = \sup_{P \neq 0} \frac{|\delta_a(P)|}{||P||_\infty} = \sup_{P \neq 0} \frac{|P(a)|}{\sup_{x \in [0, 1]}|P(x)|} $$

Any help or guidance is welcome…

Comment: If $a \in [0,1]$, then it is clear that $\delta_a$ is continuous. If $|a|>1$, then $\delta_a$ is not continuous.

Indeed, fix $a \not\in [-1,1]$. For $n \ge 1$, consider $P_n \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ defined by $P_n(x):= x^n$. Then $\|P_n \| = 1$ (because $|P_n(x)| <1$ for any $x<1$ and $|P_n(1)| = 1$). However, $|P_n(a)|=|a|^n$ tends to infinity. Thus, $\delta_a$ is not continuous if $a \not\in [-1,1]$. However, I am not sure what happen when $a \in [-1,0)$.

Comment: For $a \in [0,1]$, it is clear that $|P(a)| \le \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|P(x)|$. So, $\|\delta_a\| \le 1$. Consider $f\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ defined by $f(x):=1$ (i.e. a constant polynomial). Then $|P(a)|=1=\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |P(x)|$. Thus, $\|\delta_a\| \ge 1$. Hence $\|\delta_a\| = 1$ if $a \in [0,1]$.

Comment: To the OP. In this website it is customary to upvote or give the "green ticket" when one is satisfied with an answer. Otherwise one explains what is not appropriate in the answer

Answer (score 1):

According to tfp , it remains to consider the case when $a\in [-1,0)$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. $\delta_{-1}$ is not continuous.

$\textbf{Proof}$. For every integer $p>0$, let $y_p=x^{2p}-x^{2p-1}$.

$y_p'=x^{2p-2}(2px-2p+1)$.

$\min_{[0,1]}(y_p)<0$ is obtained for $x_p=1-\dfrac{1}{2p}$ and is equal to $m_p=(1-\dfrac{1}{2p})^{2p}-(1-\dfrac{1}{2p})^{2p-1}$. When $p\rightarrow +\infty$, $m_p\sim \dfrac{-1}{2pe}$.

Finally, when $p$ is large,

$\dfrac{|y_p(-1)|}{|m_p|}\sim 4pe$ and we are done.

EDIT. In fact, it is easier than I thought.

For every $a<0$, $\delta_a$ is not continuous.

It suffices to consider $y_p=(2x-1)^p$.

indeed $||y_p||=1$ and $y_p(a)=(2a-1)^p$ with $|2a-1|>1$.